# How do I add this list of numeric strings to a class list of integers?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing, model-view-controller

Hope the title makes sense.

I'm creating a report from a list of comma seperated integers saved as a single string in the following format:

```
2, 3, 5
```

I've split these into an array of string numbers and now want to add them to a model which contains an Int32 value so I can do a comparison against data held in another class.

```
private class multiValues
{
    private Int32 val { get; set; }
}
private class setMultiValues  : List<multiValues>
{
}
```

I was hoping it could be done using a simple for loop but I am unable to parse the string as an int for the class.

```
String[] test = answers.First().multi_choice.Split(',');
List<setMultiValues> multis = new List<setMultiValues>();

for (var i = 0; i <= test.Length; i++)
{
    multis.Add(Int32.Parse(test[i].ToString()));
}
```

Is it just a case of parsing the strings into a list of integers before adding them into the model class or is there a less hacky way of doing it?

Comment: why you inherit `setMultiValues` from `List`?

Comment: There are no spaces in the strings, that's just me typing out manually and trying to make things readable. i <= test.length is populated. Only exception I get are: 
`Error 15 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'SurveyReporting.Controllers.setMultiValues'  
HomeController.cs`

Comment: @Funk247, `setMultiValues` is class inherited from list: in your case you have `List<List<multiValues>>`, so you can't add to it simple _int_.

Comment: can you explain why you need this two classes? `multiValues` and `setMultiValues`. Also not recommended inherit from `List` better add field

Comment: without setMultiValues I get the following exception, have to admit, I'm not fully au fait with C# models and enumeration yet:

`Error 15 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SurveyReporting.Controllers.multiValues>'`
``

Comment: yourr error is because you have created a list of setMultiValues. this means than you can only add a setMultiValues object to the list Int is not a setMultiValues, if you just had a setMultiValues instead of a list of them then you could add a new multiValues object to it but again not an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing all the right things but just making them all overly complicated

You don't need multiValues at all

```
String[] test = answers.First().multi_choice.Split(',');
List<int> multis = new List<int>();

foreach (var s in test )
{
    multis.Add(int.Parse(s);
}
```

or simplified

```
var multis = from s in answers.First().multi_choice.Split(',')
select int.Parse(s);
```

or even

```
var multis = from a in answers
             select new {Answer=a,Values= from s in a.multi_choice.Split(',')
                                          select int.Parse(s)
                        };
```

this will create an unnamed type that is a answer and a list of all the int values

Comment: This did the trick for me, I just needed to check for empty vals due to a trailing comma in the string. Many thanks!

Comment: note that var multis isn't a List of Int its an Enumerable of Int, Enumerable means you can read the int from it but not add or remove them you need to use ToList to convert to a full List object

Answer (score 2):

LINQ makes this much easier:

```
var numbers = answers.First().multi_choice.Split(',').Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToList()
```

Then you can add the list to your model.

---

Update:

`Select` in LINQ is much like `SELECT` in SQL, or `map` in functional languages. It takes a list of items and a function to apply to each item in turn. In your case, you have a list of strings and a parsing function that takes a string and returns an integer (or fails!).

LINQ is the preferred way of manipulating data in C# when the manipulations are side-effect free. It is more compact and does not depend on the implementation details of the collection.

Comment: You may just use `Int32.Parse` instead of `x => Int32.Parse(x)`

Answer (score 1):

How I know - there is no way to do this less hacky, but you can simplify it by LINQ

I think it should look like this:

```
var test = answers.First().multi_choice.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
List<setMultiValues> multis = new List<setMultiValues>();

multis.AddRange(test);
```

Comment: `int` not same as `setMultiValues`

Comment: `String[] test` and you try assign `int[]` this not even compile

Comment: in the question `int` values adding to list of `setMultiValues`. I don't know, maybe he has some overriden methods of this

Comment: second comment - you sure, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
List<setMultiValues> result = answers.First().multi_choice.Split(',').Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToList<setMultiValues>()
```